# Ubuntu 20.04 reboots suddenly occasionally

Tags: 20.04, power-management, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in a desktop computer Intel i9 Core 16Gb RAM ASUS Motherboard. Sometimes, when I am running applications like OBS Studio, Skype, Chrome etc, my computer reboots suddenly. I do not know the reason for that and I could not find a proper article that can help to settle this issue. I explain my tries next in an attempt to find out probable issues with my hardware.

The result after typing `last reboot`, which shows that my previous Ubuntu run appears as "still running" after the unexpected reboot:

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Wed Aug 26 11:00   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Tue Aug 25 06:20   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 06:38 - 00:06  (17:28)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 23 18:52 - 23:36  (04:44)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 23 06:32 - 23:36  (17:04)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Thu Aug 20 09:42 - 18:17 (2+08:35)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 21:55 - 22:22  (00:26)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 09:22 - 21:55  (12:33)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 09:00 - 21:55  (12:54)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 08:55 - 21:55  (12:59)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 05:56 - 07:37  (01:40)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 17 05:34 - 07:37  (02:02)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 21:09 - 00:07  (02:58)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 20:52 - 21:09  (00:17)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 20:38 - 20:51  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 20:14 - 20:38  (00:23)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 20:05 - 20:38  (00:33)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 19:31 - 20:38  (01:07)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:39 - 19:30  (00:51)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:27 - 18:38  (00:11)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:22 - 18:27  (00:04)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:18 - 18:27  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:16 - 18:27  (00:10)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 18:11 - 18:27  (00:15)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 16:42 - 18:11  (01:28)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 16:30 - 16:42  (00:11)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 16:22 - 16:30  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 16:13 - 16:22  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 15:50 - 16:13  (00:23)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 15:46 - 16:13  (00:27)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 14:01 - 15:42  (01:41)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 16 13:50 - 14:00  (00:09)
```

The hardware configuration of the computer is given below:

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2ca
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

When I first installed Ubuntu, I tried several times to make a Nvidia driver to work, but was any of the official nvidia drivers were successful to recognize my nvidia cards. Thus, I am running Noveau driver currently.

I performed stress test on my CPU using the tool `stress-ng` and installed `powertop` to check the power consumption of my hardware devices. My computer is connected to a no-break (600 Va) and the maximum power consumption of my hardware during the stress test is 104W. According to `sensors`, the temperature of my cpu cores during the stress test are:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +92.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +91.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +87.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +92.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +91.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +92.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +91.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 6:        +89.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 7:        +89.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
```

The output of `powertop` during the same stress test:

```
System baseline power is estimated at 104 W

Power est.    Usage     Device name
  85.4 W     1065%        CPU core
  9.68 W     1065%        CPU misc
  1.01 W     1065%        DRAM
            100,0%        PCI Device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710]
            100,0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
            100,0%        USB device: USB Optical Mouse (Logitech)
            100,0%        USB device: USB Keyboard (USB)
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
            100,0%        PCI Device: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Device a2ca
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #8
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #11
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series)
            100,0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            100,0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
             18,6 pkts/s  Network interface: enp3s0 (r8169)
```

Can anyone give me a hint of what is going on with my computer? I appreciate the suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Your computer is COOKING itself. Check to make sure your fans are connected properly and operational. Check your fan settings in the BIOS. Report back.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your motherboard.

Comment: Make sure **Secure Boot** is disabled in your BIOS, then purge/reinstall Nvidia.

Comment: Hello @heynnema thanks for the support. My motherboard's model is ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. PRIME H310M-E R2.0/BR. The output of the dmidecode command is ```1402```. The Secure Boot was disabled and I tried to install all the nvidia drivers after that, but I was not successful in this task (none of the Nvidia drivers recognized my nvidia cards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CPU Temps

The `stress-ng` tool shows that CPU temps are 87.0°C to 92.0°C (almost 200°F) for all 8 CPUs. These temps will destroy your machine.

Check that your fans are properly wired, connected, and operating.

Check your BIOS for custom FAN settings.

**Get those temps down ASAP!**

## overclocking

If your CPU or RAM are overclocked, please return them to default values.

## BIOS

ASUSTeK PRIME H310M-E R2.0/BR

You have BIOS version 1402, dated 5/21/2020.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1605, dated 8/14/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/PRIME%20H310M-E%20R2.0BR/HelpDesk_Download/).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

## Nvidia

NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710]

Regarding the Nvidia problems... the current driver is version 450.66, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

Confirm that Secure Boot is disabled in the BIOS.

Purge all current Nvidia drivers, and then install the new drivers.

[image]

[image]

**Update #1:**

The message that you're getting back from the Nvidia driver indicates that 450.66 doesn't support your video card, hence they don't work on your configuration. You'll need to contact Nvidia Support to ask which driver to use. Until then, select the Nouveau video driver, and then purge all of the Nvidia stuff again.

Comment: please, see my outputs in the answer below

Comment: @ViniciusBorges Thanks for the data. However, that data should have been edited into your original question, not added as an answer. Maybe if you have a chance, you can copy/paste that data, and then delete the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ViniciusBorges It would be very instructive to run stress-ng and watch the fan outputs in sensors. Right now at idle only one fan shows as running. Your idle temps look fine, but your stress-ng temps are really bad... so if there isn't a fan problem, maybe the thermal paste on the CPU cooler/heat pipe needs to be refreshed. Also, `thermald` should never have let temps get that high, so you may have to write a customized `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` for your configuration. Search here on AU for "thermald" and you'll find plenty of examples from me... more...

Comment: @ViniciusBorges See `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`. Regarding Nvidia... show me `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Regarding the restarts... is your PSU rated high enough? Do you have any PSU diags as a part of your motherboard? We may have a PSU problem. And the last, very slight possibility, is that we have to add special kernel boot parameters, or even try a newer kernel... more on that later.

Comment: sorry for that, but the problem when creating a new answer was due to the size limit of the comment and my previous message is too long to be included in this comment.

Comment: Concerning the nvidia driver, here are some outputs: ```dkms status
nvidia, 450.66, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed```

```dpkg -l *nvidia*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching nvidiaexists.txt```

Comment: ```dmesg | tail

[  878.250193] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1281)
               NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the
               NVRM: NVIDIA 450.66 driver release.
               NVRM: Please see 'Appendix A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products'
               NVRM: in this release's README, available on the operating system
               NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.```

Comment: ```lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)
 DeviceName: Onboard - Video
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)```

Comment: ```dmesg | tail


[  878.250230] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
[  878.250240] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[  878.250241] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
[  878.250592] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237```

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I believe that the restarts problem is due to my faulty or weak PSU. After installing the Nvidia driver, the reboots became more frequent and it makes sense since Nvidia consumes more power. I also tried to plug the PC directly to the power plug instead of by means of my nobreak (600Va), but the restarts are still on. I am looking for the specifications of my PSU and attempting to estimate the power consumption of my pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112395/discussion-between-heynnema-and-vinicius-borges).

Answer (score 1):

the output of `ps auxc | grep therm` is:

```
root         228  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   07:39   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root         872  0.0  0.0 134500  9892 ?        Ssl  07:40   0:00 thermald
```

I successfully updated the BIOS Version and installed the Nvidia driver 450, but the computer restarted by itself during the installation.

The temperature of my computer when it is idle is given below:

```
sensors
nct6796-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                    328.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                        1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:                       3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                      3.41 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                        1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                      160.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                      128.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                       3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                       3.17 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                      1000.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                     152.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                     128.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                     144.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                     128.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                     136.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                     1220 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan7:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                    +32.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                    +31.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                  +110.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                  +115.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                  +114.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                  +115.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:              +34.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
                                    (crit = +100.0°C)
PECI Agent 0 Calibration:  +31.5°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:      +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:              +0.0°C  
intrusion0:               OK
intrusion1:               ALARM
beep_enable:              disabled

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +38.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +35.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +34.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +38.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +35.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +33.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +34.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 6:        +35.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 7:        +34.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

After the reboot, I saw that Nvidia 450 driver has been installed, but when I type `nvidia-smi`, I receive the message:

`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Ps.: this computer is novel... I acquired it two weeks ago.